# Term Sets Not Showing in Dropdown when defining User Profile Property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, user-profile-property

First time posting to Stack Exchange, so giving this a shot in hopes someone can help.   I had set up terms sets for various things under People term group in SPO and was able to assign them to new user profile properties I added.   Now I want to do the same thing for our on premise SharePoint 2019.  I have the same term sets defined in the on premise farm, but when I create a new user profile property, the drop down for "Pick a term set for this property" is empty.  This is one farm, so publishing the term set is not the issue.   Is there some step I have to do on premise that wasn't necessary with SPO to make the terms available to user profiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to Central Administration> Application Management> Manage Service Applications> Managed metadata Service Connection> properties as shown below:

[image]

Then check if "This service Application is the default storage location for column specific term sets" option has been ticked:

[image]

Reference:

https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2013/06/28/pick-a-term-set-for-this-property-is-empty/

Comment: Thank you.   That fixed the problem!